# Is ctrl+alt+backspace officially deprecated?

Tags: xorg

I was researching how to enable the kill X keybind, historically known as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd>, and stumbled upon this discussion:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=73617

There, in post #7, the following was said:

> In the versions of X.org-server > 1.6.0 they have disabled 'Zapping'.
>
> In that discusion it was declared that alt-sysreq-k was "better" [than
>   zap] because it's harder to hit accidentally and more reliable due to
>   being implemented in the kernel and not X.

Does that mean that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd> is officially deprecated? And the replacement is to use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Sysrq</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> (kill all processes on the current virtual console) instead?

I was not able to find the original source of said discussion. Sadly it was not linked.

Note that the discussion was from 2009.

Note also that I am not asking how to enable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd>. I am asking whether <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd> is officially deprecated.

Comment: How much more "official" would you like than shipping code in the official version of the software? Maybe an embossed certificate to go along with it?

Comment: I still use it. But then I also have ctrl-alt-del for xkill. ;)

Comment: Beware that Ctrl+Alt+Baskspace and Alt+SysRq+K are not equivalent. Ctrl+Alt+Baskspace kills the X server and lets clients live; most clients will die but they can choose to save work. Alt+SysRq+K force-kills everything.

Answer (score 3):

The bug tracker entry at https://bugs.freedesktop.org/10510 (*"Xorg should use a more unlikely key combination than Control-Alt-Backspace as the server zap key"*) was closed as "WORKSFORME" after it was pointed out that "zapping [is now] disabled by default", so I guess that's why they saw no more reason to change it. So zapping seems generally deprecated as an everyday feature.